# Get field from different model in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, multiple-inheritance

I have a model linked to a second table:

```
public class Rock
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Con")]
    public int ConID { get; set; }
    public virtual Con Con { get; set; }
}

public class Con
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Rock> Rock{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9A-Za-z '']+$")]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my control, I have a 'create' action:

```
// GET: Rock/Create/3337
    [Route("Rock/Create/{ConID?}")]
    public ActionResult Create(int? ConID)
    {
        var rock= new Rock();
        rock.ConID = (int)ConID;
        return View(rock);
    }
```

I'd like to get the con name from that table and send it to the view. At this point it doesn't know the name because there's no 'rock' record linking it yet.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a strongly typed view with `Rock` as Type, you need to either add 'Con Name' property to Rock Type or else you need to create a new Type and add the data to this Type which you want to pass to the View.

```
public class NewType
    {
        public int ConID { get; set; }
        public string ConName { get; set; }
    }
```

Add the data you want to pass in this Type and return view with this object:-

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? ConID)
    {
            var newType= new NewType();
            newType.ConID = (int)ConID;
            newType.ConName = "XYZ";
            return View(newType);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you show how to add the Con Name property to the Rock class? That would be the simplest solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

The two suggestions I would give are to pass Con.name to the view in the viewbag or to create a viewmodel, as Rahul suggested, that combines the properties of different classes that are needed for that particular view.

Comment: Thanks- I fixed the code above with Rock() instead of Rating(). But that fixed, wouldn't I get a null value for @Model.Con.Name since it's a new object?

Comment: Any way to create the new Rock with the ConID so that the Con is connected like `var rock= new Rock("ConID",ConID);`?

Comment: Yes you can assign an object to that property. e.g. `rock.Con = new Con {id = 1, name = "foo"};` But it seems that you want to load an existing object rather than create a new one.